# Can I create an foreach and combine 2 arrays based on same value in PHP in order to echo?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I struggle with below.

I have 2 query results from a Database. One Query returns always present data like a set of slots (i.e. 1-9) those get always displayed. And the other query returns only if it is present, like a job. When it is active than it gets a slot id assigned.

Note: There not always the same amount of Jobs as it is for Slots. Slots always 1-3 and in total 3, but Jobs can be 1,2 or even 5 with a Slot Status 0 and a single with an assigned Slot number, like below it is 1.

```
$ArrSlot = array(
'TABLE_NUMBER' => 1,
'TABLE_NUMBER' => 2,
'TABLE_NUMBER' => 3); 

$ArrJob = array(
    'TABLE_NUMBER' => 0,
    'TABLE_NUMBER' => 0,
    'TABLE_NUMBER' => 0,
    'TABLE_NUMBER' => 1);
```

Here it turns tricky, I want to do an foreach and echo an 'X' only if the `$ArrJob == $ArrSlot`.

Not sure how to tackle this.

What I did was:

Run the queries first, than do the foreach and echo a result from a query result which is not inner of the foreach.

```
<?php foreach($ArrSlot as $SlotList) {
if (trim($ArrJob["TABLE_NUMBER"]) == $SlotList["TABLE_NUMBER"]) 
{ echo trim($ArrJob["STATUS"]); 
} else 
{ echo "0";}
?>
```

I used a ternary, but it didn't succeed. I might be doing something very simple wrong, sorry guys doing this for quite some hours...

Comment: would you mind sharing the queries? we might be able to do this in one query.

Comment: `foreach($ArrSlot as $key => $SlotList) {
if (isset($ArrJob[$key]) && trim($ArrJob[$key]) == $SlotList) ....` assumed "TABLE_NUMBER" as different value.

Comment: @ThomasLang thank you, I solved the problem via the query.

Comment: good job! it's always better to have another look at the problem, this prevents messy and unneeded code :)

Answer (score 0):

Use array_intersect(). Consider...

```
$resultArr = array_intersect($ArrSlot,$ArrJob);
foreach($resultArr as $result)
{
  print_r($result);
}
```